# Swift 1.2 drag and drop controls and views in Cocoa

Tags: swift, cocoa, drag-and-drop, osx-yosemite

I'm building one application where I need to make a simple window and be able to drag&drop files onto this window. In this app I have to then parse file path and write out all paths of dropped files in table or nice order (one under another). App doesn't need to take more than one file at once, but this might be a feature for future.

Up to now I have managed to make simple drag&drop in NSView (which I extended with custom class). App is correctly registering drag&drop events and I get all file path and I have also figured how to get file names out of those strings.

My question is: **How can I move this "drag&drop" to NSTableView, as I wish to have file names in nicely in table?**

I have tried to put tableview under NSView but it doesn't work and if I extend NSTableView class it just registers that there was drag&drop event but nothing else happens. 
Do I have to extend other class or how to make this work? I'm implementing NSDraggingDestination protocol in custom class and using performDragOperation function.

I would like to have:
- whole app window can take drag&drop-ed files, not matter where I drop it it has to accept file and put file name into table

I'm sorry if this might sound trivial but I have just started learning swift and developing OS X apps and I'm not used to this new API and don't really know how all things works here.

Comment: You're asking many (good) questions here actually. Try to narrow down your needs and ask *one* question per post about a specific problem. // 1. How to drag'n'drop anywhere on the app. 2. How to sort and store the dropped info. 3. How to present the info in a table view. Etc. By the way this is not trivial and needs work :), so answering about all this in one single answer would be too long.